# Storing Data With Python in Text Files

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, storage, storing-data

Similar questions have been asked but none quite like this.

I need to save 2 pieces of information in a text file, the username and their associated health integer. Now I need to be able to look into the file and see the user and then see what value is connected with it. Writing it the first time I plan to use open('text.txt', 'a') to append the new user and integers to the end of the txt file.

my main problem is this, How do I figure out which value is connected to a user string? If they're on the same line can I do something like read the only the number in that line?

What are your guys' suggestions? If none of this works, I guess I'll need to move over to json.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) may be what you're looking for.  I'd suggest reading one line at a time to parse through the text file.

Another method would be to read the entire txt and separate strings using something like  `text_data.split("\n")`, which should work if the data is separated by line (denoted by '\n').

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) which is designed for just that!

**Construct a new configuration**

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.sections()
[]
>>> config['Players'] = {
...     "ti7": 999,
...     "example": 50
... }
>>> with open('example.cfg', 'w') as fh:
...     config.write(fh)  # write directly to file handler
...
```

**Now read it back**

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read("example.cfg")
['example.cfg']
>>> print(dict(config["Players"]))
{'ti7': '999', 'example': '50'}
```

**Inspecting the written file**

```
% cat example.cfg
[Players]
ti7 = 999
example = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a text config written in the form `key value` in each line, you can probably parse your config file as follows:

```
user_healths = {}                              # start empty dictionary
with open("text.txt", 'r') as fh:              # open file for reading
    for line in fh.read().strip().split('\n'): # list lines, ignore last empty
        user, health = line.split(maxsplit=1)  # "a b c" -> ["a", "b c"]
        user_healths[user] = int(health)       # ValueError if not number
```

Note that this will make the user's health the last value listed in `text.txt` if it appears multiple times, which may be what you want if you always append to the file

```
% cat text.txt
user1 100
user2 150
user1 200
```

Parsing `text.txt` above:

```
>>> print(user_healths)
{'user1': 200, 'user2': 150}
```